# Update field in parent when a related record is added

Tags: trigger, lookup

I would like to know that is there any way my trigger will be fired when any record is added to a related list .

Right now , The trigger iterates through the related list records and updates a field in Account .

So suppose a new record is added to the related list , the field will not be updated unless the account is edited . Is there any way it can be updated ?

Edit :Here Account and Client are in Lookup relationship.

```
trigger ABCD on Account (before insert, after update) {
    if(RecursiveClass.updateOnce == false){
        RecursiveClass.updateOnce = true;
        List<Account> AccList = [Select id, Field1__c, (Select Id, Status__c from Clients__r) from Account WHERE Id IN: trigger.new];
        List<Account> updateList = new List<Account>();
        Integer demoField = 0;
        for (Account acc: AccList) {
            for (Client pc: acc.Clients__r) {
                If(pc.Status__c != 'Lapsed') { 
                    demoField++;
                }
            }
            acc.Field1__c = demoField;
            updateList.add(acc);
        }
        if(updateList.size()>0){
            update updateList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your trigger is on account,  that is incorrect, your trigger should be on child object

Comment: Which field are you referring to that would be updated if edited in Account, account.Field1__c? Right now, your trigger doesn't make sense. How would Account know if a new Clients__r is inserted? What will cause it to fire?

Comment: There is an already created solution for a similar problem https://github.com/abhinavguptas/Salesforce-Lookup-Rollup-Summaries

Comment: @crmprogdev - I would want to update count of Field1__c in Account if status__c in any related record != lapsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comments, your trigger needs to be firing on your related objects, NOT on Account. This is what's referred to as a roll-up count trigger. The entry condition would be for it to fire when a record's current `status__c != lapsed` (taken from trigger.new) and the previous value (taken from trigger.old if there was one) of `status__c == lapsed`. There's a managed package from the App Exchange that will do this for free for a limited number of fields on a single object called [Roll-up Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI).

Answer (score 1):

Write trigger on the related record. Whenever a new Client is added update its corresponding parent Account.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/47262)

Comment: @SebastianKessel why do yo think that this is not an answer? Maybe it is not very detailed but it describes what to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Because a one line post with no context or code should be a comment to the question, not an answer. If you are going to answer the question then give the OP more than a passing comment about how to solve his/her problem.

Comment: @SebastianKessel He has written most of answer by him self. He just had to write it at the right place. Anyways thanks for the valuable feedback. I will improve as per site standards. :)

Comment: @Shankish, that's all that it's needed. We should strive to make our answers comprehensive and detailed (ergo, helpful), otherwise, rookie/newbie developers might end up with more questions than answers.